# Web Scraper Using django (python for web)

Tags: python, django, scrape

It's been a month or so, yeah?

I've been searching the web for web scraping using python and I have found beautifulSoup and lots of other scraping tools such as Scrapy, scraper, etc.

**All of them are the same...a little differences there might be..**

Most tutorials I watch or read, are the same to...

Okay, what I am trying to do here is the following:

Except of putting the URL that I wanna scrape into the code...**I want the USER to INPUT the url and then the scraper scrapes that url that the user has pasted in the HTML  field**

All tutorials have the code like this:

```
url = (http://......)
```

No...I want it somehow like this:

```
url = (USER INPUT)
```

Example video:
[Link scraper](https://youtu.be/Wo5eMclb-G4?t=65)

It's funny how he didn't actually to this in his tutorials...I think?

but yes, that's what I am trying to do, if you have any tutorial or documentation of doing this, please please help me out!!

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your view

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

create a form from where the user will post the url for scrapping

in the specific view function

```
url = form.cleaned_data.get['name of the input field']
data = requests.get(url)
```

and then do what you need to do with your scrapped data

Answer (score 4):

If your using django, set up a form with a text input field for the url on your html page. On submission this url will appear in the POST variables if you've set it up correctly. Then in your back end, where you handle the url that was POST'd, grab the user's input url.
see https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_forms/ if you don't know how to set up a form.